# Can Blazor create wasm modules without any UI references or code?

Tags: blazor

Looking at the Blazor documentation I get the impression that it is meant to be used to develop client side browser applications.

A subset of this should be creating WASM output in the same way Rust does, but I cannot see any documentation that explains how can I create standalone WASM output which then can be called from JavaScript or if I can do it at all.

So is it possible to use Blazor or Belero (its F# cousin, based on Blazor) to create wasm libraries and not full applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A subset of this should be creating WASM output in the same way Rust does

No.

Blazor runs on Mono. Mono itself is compiled to Wasm, but both Blazor and your software run as IL modules inside Mono. In the current implementation they are interpreted, not compiled to Wasm.

> So is it possible to use Blazor [or ...] to create wasm libraries and not full applications?

No.

**Update 2022:** Mono is now just the dotnet runtime (6+) and you can now create Wasm code from C# without using Blazor.

The basic steps are [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/blob/ce43f371e1761fe6335f8c63d344e605b892ebe9/docs/using-nativeaot/compiling.md#webassembly) but I think you will need a little more to get a working app/library. Like installing the framework etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Based on your answer, this looks like a tooling limit rather than a tech limit. There is an interpreter running in the browser but no tooling to create and deploy a class library of sorts into that interpreter.

Comment: You can deploy a class lib alright, as long as you don't care about what it is compiled to...  Wasm will be a little faster but for the rest you have all the same features and limitations.

Comment: Nice, I will delete my comments to keep the post clean. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [ASP.NET Core Razor components class libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio). Those libraries can contains code only such as services, and js interop scripts.

I wrote this library for exemple to use some AWS services in a Blazor app : [Aguacongas.AwsServices](https://github.com/aguacongas/football-championship/tree/master/src/Aguacongas.AwsServices)